# Safari and Background-Images

Tags: css, safari, background-image, mobile-safari

i try to set some background-images as inline style. But safari doesn't display the images. My second try was to set the background-images in my stylesheet file - this works finde.

But the problem is: The background-images are be set dynamic from wordpress.

Know anyone here a solution for this problem?
I only want to work with inline styles.

**EDIT:**

Inline-Style for Background-Images:

```
<div class="myBgCon" style="background-image:url(http://www.myurl.nic/de/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/75582286.jpg); "> ... </div>
```

**style.css**

```
.myBgCon {
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position:  center top;
background-size:cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
height:450px; width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Provide some code, we can't know what you're doing wrong without seeing what exactly you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i have found a solution.
All CSS Styles are valid.

But the CSP (Content Secruity Policy) has blocked some inline styles.